# Submitting one out of many inputs on a page to mysql database using wordpress

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

At current I managed to get a form on a wordpress page to submit data to a mysql database (a very large victory for me; not big into php/coding)

This is the code I have been using, but need help changing:

```
<form method="post">
Value1: <input type="text" name="field1" />
Value2: <input type="text" name="field2" />
Value3: <input type="text" name="field3" />
Value4: <input type="text" name="field4" />
Value5: <input type="text" name="field5" />
<input type="submit" /></form>


$newdb = new wpdb( 'username', 'password', 'database', 'localhost' );

$field1 = $_POST['field1'];
$field2 = $_POST['field2'];
$field3 = $_POST['field3'];
$field4 = $_POST['field4'];
$field5 = $_POST['field5'];

$newdb->insert("test", array(
"field1" => $field1,
"field2" => $field2,
"field3" => $field3,
"field4" => $field4,
"field5" => $field5
   ));
```

As you can see, this causes all the inputs on the page to be submitted, and ends up creating blank cells in my table rows when there is no data inserted into the fields.

**I need to be able to submit each input *separately***, hopefully without creating a seperate php script for each input, and without entering blank cells in my table.

Comment: *"As you can see, this causes all the inputs on the page to be submitted, and ends up creating blank cells"* - You need to use a conditional statement, since form defaults to self by default. Or, use seperate files for the form and PHP. That is why you're getting blank entries on initial page load.

Comment: Would you be so kind as to provide me with an example instead of downvotes?

Comment: How do you know I was the one who downvoted? Plus, this is an easy fix for the first part. `isset()`

Comment: I don't, but since you're the only one who answered, I can only assume. I'm only asking for help, I thought this was the purpose of this format. 

I'm going on previous experience, asking for help seems to result in mostly getting your hand slapped and told "you're an idiot" in essence.

Also thanks.

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php

Comment: what is creating blank spaces? are they all required?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want o avoid inserting blanks, you just need to check each input before inserting it.

For example,

```
$inserts = array();
for ($i = 1; $i < 6; $i++) {
    $fieldName = 'field' . $i . '-name';
    if ($_POST[$fieldName]) {
        $inserts[$field-name] = $_POST[$fieldName];
    }
} 
$newdb->insert("test", $inserts);
```